# How to Take the number of days from specific month in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want count days from specific month. I see from documentation Codeigniter, use this function.

```
echo days_in_month(06, 2005);
```

On that function, we must add int month and year. I want take number of days from month and year be dynamic without we add int month and year.
Ex : i want take number of days from this month and this year.

Comment: use this method cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,06,2005);

Comment: actually there's a PHP function to call this using 't' format in PHP date function. `echo date('t');` it will count the number of days of current month and year. You could add parameter like `echo date('t', mktime(0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2017));` if you want to choose specific date..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$pass_date = strtotime('2016-06-29');
$total_days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, date('m', $pass_date), date('Y', $pass_date));
echo $total_days;
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use below function

```
<?php
    $d = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,6,2005);
    echo $d.' Days';
?>
```

Resource from  https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_cal_cal_days_in_month.asp